# How to make correct substitutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, substitution

> If the sum of the roots of quadratic equation, $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $12$ then the sum of the roots of the equation $a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)+c=0$ is?

I can solve this by procedural way using sum of roots concept, but when I saw the solution in book they wrote:

> $\alpha+\beta=12$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are the roots of first  equation.
>
> Now, let $x=\alpha-1\implies\alpha=x+1$,
>
> replace $x$ by $x=1$
>
> $$a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)+c=0$$ $\implies$ Roots are $\alpha-1, \beta-1$.
>
> Now sum: $\alpha-1+\beta-1=10$

My question is why and how did they substituted $x=\alpha-1$, is it allowed to fix variability of equation by known, and if we substituted something like $\alpha-a=x$ where $a\neq 1$ and followed same step, why we'll not get other answer?

I'm not comfortable with these substitution, please help.

Comment: Please fix the problem statement, there are missing words.

Comment: If it helps, there are other ways to solve your problem. For a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, the sum of the roots is always $-\frac{b}{a}$. Now apply this to $a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c = ax^2 + (2a + b)x + (a + b + c) = 0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, fixed.

Comment: The reason for this substitution is that we know something good about the roots of $g(x)=f(x-1)$  Specifically, we know that the roots of $g(x)$ sum to $12$,  But if $r,s$ are the roots of $g$ then the roots of $f$ are $r-1,s-1$.  You are free to make whatever substitution you like, but if you tried, say, $h(x)=f(x+7)$ you wouldn't get anywhere because you don't know anything relevant about the polynomial $h$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $x_0+x_1=12$.

Let $x=x'+1$. Then the sum of the roots of $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x'+1)^2+b(x'+1)+c=0$$ is $x_0+x_1=12=x'_0+1+x'_1+1$ and $$x'_0+x'_1=10.$$

Comment: why $x'_0+1$ and $x'_1+1$  satisfy $a(x'+1)^2+b(x'+1)+c=0$? please explain.

Comment: Because $x'+1=x$.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

Rewriting the first equation with the variable y:

$ay^2  +by + c = 0$,  $ y_1 + y_2 = 12$.

Note: Setting  $y = x+ 1$ in the first equation gives the second equation.

Hence:

$y_1 + y_2 = (x_1 + 1) + ( x_2 + 1)  = 12$;

$x_1 + x_2 =10$, where

$x_1,x_2$ are the roots of

$a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c =0$.